# How to wait until Excel calculates a formula in xlwings?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlwings

I am introducing a formula in Excel and I need to wait until the formula returns a list of values.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

wb = xw.Book()  
wb.sheets['Sheet1'].range('A1').value = formula

#  wait until the formula return some data

#  ...

# read data as dataframe

df = wb.sheets['Sheet1'].range('A1').expand().options(pd.DataFrame).value
```

Answer (score 1):

The Excel API has the property [CalculationState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculationstate). Example - uses time module from standard library:

```
while wb.app.api.CalculationState != xlwings.constants.CalculationState.xlDone:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer but it does not work. I need to wait until one formula, which makes a connection with a server, returns some data.